# How can I redirect old pages with question marks in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have read about htaccess redirect and rewrite on stackoverflow and on other sites and learned how to redirect simple pages and directories, but there are about 30 links remaining that I haven't been able to redirect. The reason appears to be because they contain "**?**" in the link's URL. I've tried the solutions posted but I haven't been able to make enough sense of them to succeed.

These work:

```
Redirect /Corpfleet.php     htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/wraps.php
Redirect /drivers.php       htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/drivers.php
Redirect /galleries.php     htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/galleries.php
```

These do NOT work:

```
Redirect /ad.php?View=FAQ       htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/advertiser-faqs.php
Redirect /ad.php?View=gallery   htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/galleries.php
Redirect /ad.php?View=Materials htp://www.marketyourcar.cm/products-services.php
```

*Yes, I know that the URL above is htp and .cm - I had to break it in order to make this post with my low reputation level.*

If anyone can help with this I'd appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: I think part of my problem here is that I am giving you guys the live server info instead of the dev server info. I am not testing this code on the live location, so I have to edit everything to suit the dev setup:

The files sit here:
`http://clients.lancedaoust.com/myc/`

So I've edited the code you've given me to suit that:
`RewriteRule /myc/ad.php?View=FAQ$ http://www.marketyourcar.com/advertiser-faqs.php [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect from like:

**site.com/index.php?blabla=1&id=32**

to

**site.com/contact.html**

then use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} blabla=1&id=32
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/contact.html? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` can't handle that. `RewriteRule` can. This should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ad\.php\?View\=FAQ$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/advertiser-faqs.php [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/ad\.php\?View\=gallery$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/galleries.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/ad\.php\?View\=Materials$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/products-services.php [R=301,L]
```

Or try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ad.php?View=FAQ$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/advertiser-faqs.php [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/ad.php?View=gallery$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/galleries.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/ad.php?View=Materials$ http://www.marketyourcar.cm/products-services.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it but it didn't work: it produced a 404.

"Not Found
The requested URL /ad.php was not found on this server."

Comment: I just followed a tutorial on how to use mod_rewrite and it worked, so I'd say yes, it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ad.php?View=FAQ$  http://www.marketyourcar.cm/advertiser-faqs.php? [R=301,L]
```

Add a trailing `?` to the substitution URL to remove the incoming query.